# instagram basic display API get request not working?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to do a basic get request based on the short-lived token recieved from a previous request to instagram. I know the short-lived-access-token is valid.
The account i'm testing with is a test user and the app is in development mode at facebooks end. Furthermore, the app review is currently pending but i dont think that's the issue since the account i'm testing is a test account and again - the login feature is set to development mode.

When i do the request based on the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/

i get the following response with status code 400:

> Sorry, this content isn't available right now

based on this request format:

```
  https://graph.instagram.com/access_token
  ?grant_type=ig_exchange_token
  &client_secret={instagram-app-secret}
  &access_token={short-lived-access-token}
```

Here is the full response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "Invalid OAuth access token."
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-request-id: Al1knRjoI2Qw1XEVlh4b3Ku
x-fb-trace-id: GasPh1zh4bl
x-fb-rev: 1004118369
X-FB-Debug: 73PsZ2YPe6C2obr8nIdox2r2YOtNoVsuva4y2rRLvd70l06oV8kfdjOzLRhPvLDvpsmc1+5gP42Hc4Pi4AUHLw==
Date: Fri, 16 Jul 2021 04:19:09 GMT
X-FB-TRIP-ID: 1512268381
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 45

Sorry, this content isn't available right now
```

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem too, but fortunately stumbled upon the solution. What was missing for me that I wasn't requesting the *instagram_graph_user_profile* permission when authorizing the user.

This permission is listed as being required for the [access_token endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/access_token#reading), and for me made the difference between getting "Sorry, this content isn't available" and a long-lived access token.

i.e.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
    ?client_id={app-id}
    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
    &scope=user_profile,user_media,instagram_graph_user_profile
    &response_type=code
```

Answer (score 3):

Exchanging access_token can be tricky sometimes. Let me walk you through another way to get the access_token.

- First, we make a GET call to get the auth code. Scope depends on the permission given to the Test app.

```
https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={your_redirect-uri}&auth_type={rerequest}scope={email}
```

- Now, Your Test App needs login access which further gets redirected to the URL mentioned in the test app. The URL consists of code. Copy the code and don't include #*=* part.
- To get the access token now we make another GET request.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URL}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&code=${oauth_code}
```

- This gives you access_token. Copy the access_token and paste that in Access Token Debugger [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/). You will find out that this comes with no expiry date.